# Ensure specific containers keep running even if /var/lib/docker partition is full?

Tags: docker, diskspace, reliability

I maintain a lot of Docker containers. I know that the most common failure mode is running out of disk space in /var/lib/docker, which can completely paralyze Docker - after reboot, it might not go up at all. Is there a way to protect specific ultra-sensitive projects running on a server from running out of /var/lib/docker?

The only option I can think of is moving them to a separate VM, but that creates issues with resource management for the host.

Could I make sure the state of some containers (including metadata and the underlying images) lives outside of /var/lib/docker?

Or could I run two instances of dockerd on the same host? docker-in-docker is not really an option given that it doesn't seem to work well with sharing volumes from the host directory, which I need given that some containers share a volume and I need to specify where it lives.